How to handle mixtures of real and ideal gases for transport properties?
I have been working on implementing the Chung viscosity and thermal conductivity models from "The Properties of Gases and Liquids", 5th edition book. The models utilize critical properties such as the critical temperature, critical volume, and critical pressure. I have seen that the Chung method has issues for a single ideal gas (as the equations utilize the critical volume in the denominator of the expression for viscosity for example). I could play games with the expressions to try and place minimum values of $V_{\text{critic}}, \ T_{\text{critic}}$, etc., but that feels very ad-hoc.
My primary question is: for mixtures of real and ideal gases, is there an established way of estimating the viscosity of the mixture?
